# Cant see edges of my screen. How do I fix it?

Tags: drivers, display

I have a Hisense 42" LCD TV (1080p) connected via HDMI to my ASUS K53E laptop and when I switch it to 1080p (second screen only) I cant see the edges of my screen, and it says my TV is a Hitachi 52" not Hisense 42".
Also when I look at the "About this computer" section under Graphics it says Driver: Unknown and Experience: Standard. Im not sure what to do. Any help would be great, thanks.
My OS is Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit edition btw.

Comment: This is a common problem called '[Overscan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overscan)'. Can you please try browsing the [overscan questions answered here already](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=overscan), and see if one solves the issue for you? This is probably a duplicate but you should confirm it first.